# What is the fastest way to generate a dynamic lag variable that updates with each iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few hundred thousand groups through which I want to iterate this particular lag operation. Below is a sample where Buy_Ord_No is the group by variable:

[image: Sample Table\e]

I would like to generate Lag_Exec_Qty and Exec_Qty. What I am basically doing here is initially setting Exec_Qty equal to 0 when Buy_Act_Type = 1 or Buy_Act_Type = 4. Then, I take the lag value of Exec_Qty ad Lag_Exec_Qty. In the same row, I sum up Trd_Qty and Lag_Exec_Qty to get the updated Exec_Qty.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
for b in buy:
    temp=buy_sorted_file[buy_sorted_file["Buy_Ord_No"]==b]
    temp=temp.sort_values(["Buy_Ord_No","Buy_Ord_Txn_Time"], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)

    for index in range(len(temp.index)):
        if(int(temp["Buy_Act_Type"].iloc[index])==1 or int(temp["Buy_Act_Type"].iloc[index])==4):
            temp["Exec_Qty"].iloc[index]=0
            temp["Lag_Exec_Qty"].iloc[index]=0
        else:
            temp["Lag_Exec_Qty"].iloc[index]=temp["Exec_Qty"].iloc[index-1]
            temp["Exec_Qty"].iloc[index]=temp["Trd_Qty"].iloc[index]+temp["Lag_Exec_Qty"].iloc[index]
    if (len(buy_sorted_exec_file.index) == 0):
        buy_sorted_exec_file = temp.copy()
    else:
        buy_sorted_exec_file = pd.concat([temp,buy_sorted_exec_file]).reset_index(drop=True)
buy_sorted_file= buy_sorted_exec_file.sort_values(["Buy_Ord_Txn_Time", "Buy_Ord_Limit_Pr"],ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The code takes a really long time to run. Is there anyway through which I can speed this process up?

Comment: This would be so much easier to test if we had an actual table with the data instead of a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do, without any loops:

```
temp['Lag_Exec_Qty'] = temp['Exec_Qty'].shift(1)
temp['Exec_Qty'] = temp['Trd_Qty'] + temp['Lag_Exec_Qty']
```